# Cannot call function to concatenate it with a string

Tags: haskell

This error doesn't make sense for me:

```
    url1 = "https://someUrl.com/"
    url2 = url1 ++ "/fdsfdsfd/fdsgfdgfd"

    No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of `+'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
```

What's the matter? Syntax-wise, everything is ok, isn't it?

Comment: You need to use `(++)` not `(+)`

Comment: someone edited the question and now it doesn't make sense

Comment: Now the code in your question is correct - it doesn't exhibit the problem you had when you asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `(+)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a` so it takes two numeric arguments. To concatenate two strings you need to use `(++)` which has type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`. Since strings are `[Char]`, this gives you the result you want.